# What would be the optimal schema.org type for a public service?

Tags: schema.org

I'm looking for the best `organisation` of `localBusiness` type for a public service (sewage management) What would be the best type?

Comment: Optimal for what purpose?

Comment: Optimal on a website for crawlers to find the service

Comment: Which website crawlers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual procedure is to start from the 2 entities which you named and then check the list for **more specific types** and go step by step trying to get more specifically towards your type of business (sewage management).

For what you need to know you are more the expert yourself than the webmaster experts here. You basically have to try to position sewage management in the domain tree provided by Schema.org trying to get as specific as possible (or provided by the schema)